# How to restrict user from accessing parent form until responding to current form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to design a simple License Key client program where the user cannot access the parent form until they activate their software, and I can't seem to block them from clicking on the parent form and interacting with it. I don't want to use Form.ShowDialog() because I want both to open at the same time if the user hasn't claimed their license key. Any thoughts on how I may accomplish this?

EDIT: Here is my MainApp constructor:

```
  public MainApp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MySqlConnection conn;
        this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(MainApp_FormClosing);
        string connString = "";
        string sql = String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM license_keys WHERE hwid='{0}';", ComputerInfo.GetComputerId());
        using (conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                var result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    AuthTest authTest = new AuthTest();
                    authTest.ShowDialog(this);
                    authTest.BringToFront();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, I want both forms to open up if the SQL query does not return anything, but I want the main form (this class) to still show up, but give the user a warning (sound and flicker) if they try to interact with it before responding to the AuthTest form.

Please note that this is simply a proof of concept and I understand the code isn't great.

Comment: That's what `ShowDialog` is used for, so if that's not the result you're getting, you're using it wrong. Without the code, we can't help you figure out what you need to fix.

Comment: @madreflection Edited the post to include the logic.

Comment: Don't display UI on a worker thread.  Consequences are far worse than a dialog that isn't modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the parent window.  There's an overload that accepts `IWin32Window`.

First, you need to do this at a point where the window exists, like the `Load` event handler, not the constructor.  Because the window isn't visible yet by default, you need to call `Show` to make it visible before showing the modal dialog.

```cs
this.Show();

AuthTest authTest = new AuthTest();
authTest.ShowDialog(this);           // Assuming 'this' is the main window instance.
```

If `this` isn't the main window instance in that context, you need to pass a viable parent to whatever method that is.

The call to `authTest.BringToFront` won't execute until the dialog is dismissed so you don't need it.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this answer and I've tried it. The problem is, the program still opens the AuthTest form first, and then only opens the main form after the AuthTest form has been closed.

Comment: Where is this running, then? The constructor? Form_Load? Show more of the class, please.

Comment: its running in the constructor.

Comment: It needs to be done in the `Load` event handler and you need to call `this.Show` first. The window (HWND) doesn't exist yet when the constructor is running so there's no way it can show at that point.